# Will this code free memory allocated for MULTIMAP?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a multimap and a pointer to the multimap . Say i have multimap 
`typedef multimap<class1, class2*> LO_Index;` . I also have `LO_Index *  _index;` Which points to multimap. To Free all the memory spaces allocated for this maop I am performing the following operation . I have a Reset function which does the following to free all the memory space alocated for this `multimap`:

```
    for ( LO_Index ::iterator i = _index->begin(); i != _index->end(); i++ )
            delete (*i).second;

    // Delete all entries in the index
    _index->erase( _index->begin(), _index->end() );
```

What i have read in case of set is that setname.clear() actually doesnot free all the allocated space . But in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/erase/ I found about erase that

> This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements
>   removed, calling each element's destructor.

So i guess it will actually free the allocated spaces. But I want to confirm whether the code written in my reset function is actually freeing the memory or not.

Comment: You should think about using smart pointers.

Comment: Why not call `clear` if you remove all elements? If I did not get something wrong you call `delete` on an `int`, what is that supposed to do?

Comment: @nabulke Thanks for the alternate sugestion . But There must be ways provided to make sure that spaces allocated by these STL containers are freed .

Comment: Calling a destructor and freeing memory are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a multimap, delete (*i).second can't compile because you can only delete objects via a pointer and an int is not a pointer.

About the erase function: as far as you are concerned, the entries are removed from the container.  The allocator might decide not to return the memory, but cache it for reuse, however, this matters only in limited cases.

Comment: Sorry for the incovience in my case it is a pointer only i had put it as a char abd int just as a reference. How can i make allocator to return memory ?

Comment: @Ritesh: see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Allocators.html for more information on allocators.  About the "char abd int just as a reference", this is not clear to me, you either use a pointer or you don't and if you use a raw pointer that points to a new'ed object, you must delete it at some point.