# How can i make sure that memory allocated in case of MULTIMAP is freed

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a multimap from which I want to free the memory allocated to multimap.

I have posed a query related to this in one of the other question in Stackoverflow 
[Will this code free memory allocated for MULTIMAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665288/will-this-code-free-memory-allocated-for-multimap/9665405#comment12277683_9665405) .

My question is that whether using an erase in multimap makes sure if all memory space allocated for multimap is freed ?

Comment: I'll just repeat after @nabulke: consider using smart pointers.

Comment: Just my opinion but best would be (for OP) to understand how variables, pointers, allocations and such stuff works

Comment: @Ritesh: Are you sure you really understand the difference between the memory the multimap is allocating itself (via its `Allocator`) and the memory __you__ are allocating for the elements (via `new`)? If you understand the difference, which of the two allocations are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a clear() (or erase() with begin() and end()), all memory for items **That the multimap** have allocated will be released.

This works perfectly well for say, stocking ints.

If you allocate memory and then stock pointers in a multimap, you'll need to free that memory up yourself.

It works "as usual", you allocate -> you free it up, for ints, chars and multimaps, it is up to them to free memory they have allocated.

Answer (score 3):

The standard does not specify whether erasing an element from a container will deallocate all memory for that element; the only guarantee is that the destructor of each erased object will be called exactly once. I can't imagine why you might need a guarantee that the memory is deallocated, but if you do then you'll have to check the particular implementation you're using.